# Map Problem: Connecting multiple keys to a single list

Tags: apex, list, map

I'm having an issue with the Map Collection. I'm trying to merge some duplicates. I have value that identifies the dupes `Number__c` and is appearing on multiple accounts that need to be merged.

I'm trying to create a map that has the `Number__c` as the key for the list of `Account` records that have that id. However, I end up creating a the same list for ever Key (`Number__c`) in the Map.

Output is currently like this.

- Key = 1, List ( Id001, Id002, Id003)
- Key = 2, List ( Id001, Id002,
  Id003)
- Key = 3, List ( Id001, Id002, Id003)

Here is the code so far. I completed the SOQL query earlier to get All accounts for the loop.

```
for(integer i=0; i < allAccts.size(); i++){    
             if (allAccts.get(i).Rating__c == 'Do Not Use' ) {
                 masterRec = allAccts.get(i);
                 allAccts.remove(i); 

            List<Id> dupes = new List<Id>(); 
            for(Account b : allAccts){  
                 if (masterRec.Number__c == b.Number__c && masterRec.Id != b.Id) {

                     dupes.add(b.Id); 

                 } 
                 mapRaccts.put(masterRec.Number__c, dupes );
```

Comment: What is `masterRec`? Does this code even compile?

Comment: Yes, the code compiles. It was declared further up. See answer below it works. I had initialized masterRec prior to the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem is that you assigning every account as master account `masterRec = allAccts.get(i)` and adding all the accounts to the list for each key `dupes.add(b.Id)` and so for every key, you are getting all accounts.

Also note below points:

- This is a very low performant code because you are iteration over all accounts for each account because of inner loop. So, just for 100 accounts, you will be iteration 10,000 times.
- You should be iteration over generic for loop `for (variable : list_or_set)` instead of `for (init_stmt; exit_condition; increment_stmt)` so that you dont have to depend on size(). [Check here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for.htm).

Below is the code you can implement:

```
    List<Account> allAccts  = [SELECT Id, Name, Number__c FROM Account LIMIT 50000];
    Map<String, List<Account>> dupesMap = new Map<String, List<Account>>();

    for(Account acc : allAccts) {
        if(!dupesMap.containsKey(acc.Number__c)) {
            dupesMap.put(acc.Number__c, new List<Account>());
        }
        dupesMap.get(acc.Number__c).add(acc);
    }

    // further processing of dupesMap
```

Comment: Thank you sir! The information you gave me here is something I had been trying to figure out and has many more implications for my other projects. Really appreciate your help. #GreenCheck